# kafka broker go offline due to heap OOM

Tags: apache-kafka

We recently find our kafka cluster go offline in production environment
There are four brokers,replicationFactor is 2 and  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS is  -Xmx30G -Xms30G

Server.log:

```
[2018-10-18 14:12:01,340] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-3], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@785b3ea5 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 3 was disconnected before the response was read
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$3(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:114)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$3$adapted(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.recursivePoll$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:136)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.pollContinuously$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:142)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingSendAndReceive$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:108)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:249)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:234)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2018-10-18 14:12:03,959] INFO [GroupCoordinator 4]: Preparing to restabilize group 8017 with old generation 11 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-10-18 14:12:03,958] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2018-10-18 14:12:02,156] ERROR [KafkaApi-4] Error when handling request {replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=100,min_bytes=1,topics=[{topic=**********,partitions=[{partition=9,fetch_offset=3610091552,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=13,fetch_offset=3673665102,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=1,fetch_offset=3685463160,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=10,fetch_offset=3628517926,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=5,fetch_offset=3653905643,max_bytes=1048576}]}]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2018-10-18 14:12:02,155] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2018-10-18 14:12:01,342] ERROR [ExpirationReaper-4], Error due to  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
```

And before this happened, The cluster also got a lot ZK expired a few hours ago

```
./controller.log.2018-10-18-12:[2018-10-18 12:05:51,300] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-12:[2018-10-18 12:42:43,576] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:00:54,919] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:12:26,598] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:24:22,851] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:29:09,095] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:33:14,948] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:37:45,249] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:43:55,640] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:48:53,711] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:51:29,411] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-13:[2018-10-18 13:57:27,588] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-14:[2018-10-18 14:03:20,452] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
./controller.log.2018-10-18-14:[2018-10-18 14:06:14,026] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 4], ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect (kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
```

Can anybody look into this?

==============================================================

Screenshots for more detail:
There is a unnormal situation that day as bellow 
[Zabbix monitor information for Kafka topic producer volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSUIK.jpg)

The incoming volume for some topic is ten thousand times as common as usual. But when we Check the upstream producer's log, It's going well with normal production volume

Comment: The version of kafka is 0.10

Comment: Replication factor generally only affects disk, not heap, so how many total topics to you have and how many partitions does each broker maintain? Plus, the most useful information would actually be a heap dump, not logs. See about adding `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @cricket, thanks for the reply
We've got 49 topics and 16 partitions for most partitions,
When the oom  occur ,we try to get the dump with command like:jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump, but get "Can’t attach to the process" error ,
We now have added HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError param,
I just want to figure out the possible reason for this problem. I also search for many document about Kafka oom but so far haven't get anything helpful which is similar with our situation

Comment: Have you recently enabled SSL?

Comment: No we have not enable ssl

Comment: There might be several reasons, but I'm guessing there's a specific topic (or more) that's overwhelming your cluster. Besides that, newer versions of Kafka have done some work on addressing memory problems

Comment: cricket: You mean some topic volume maybe too large for the cluster? Does this cause by producer or consumer?
By the way there is a unnormal situation on some topic during that day. Please refer to my screenshots for the above questions.

Comment: @GavinGu Were you able to fix your problem? Were your brokers back to a healthy state? I'm finding similar issue. A broker (in container) was restarted and the other brokers still complaining about `Connection to 1 was disconnected before the response was read` after 17 hours of restart.

Comment: @xmar, We restart kafka cluster that day,and so far the problem did not happen again.Monitoring was added to zabbix in case of it. If you find something useful,pls tell me

Comment: @GavinGu Thanks. So, was it produced by too big data volumes, and since you haven't had these volumes again, it didn't appear? Or have you had these or higher volumes, and it worked OK?

Comment: @xmar, We've checked the producer and it didn't produce so large data volumes, seem like the problem come from the kafka cluster itself. We added some monitoring item since then and the problem don't happen again

Comment: It happened to us after heavy data rate import (1000 events per sec, which each triggers an average of 3x ingestions through a Kafka Streams topology) on a 3-node, 3x replication, 8MB RAM, 64-partition-per-topic cluster. But we expect to do this from time to time, and we need to rely on Kafka handling it! It's one of Kafka's strengths, so I got the feeling there may be something wrong in my config or lack of tuning for this case (or lack of metal). Thanks!

Comment: @xmar, You can check the zk log for detail info. Make sure zk timeout is large enough for the heartbeat interval. Or you can check the gc log for kafka when this problem come out. hope this could help.

Comment: Yes, I increased Zk timeout session to 1 min, plus checked GC times that were high. Now I have tuned JVM too, let's see what happens. Thanks!